# PHP pass variable through location name

Tags: php, html, post, session-variables

I have inherited this website at my work and it is written in php5, html4, and javascript. The way they pass variables from one page to another is like this:

```
filename.php?variable=value&secondvariable=secondvalue
```

So when submitting a form I've seen

```
<form method="post" name="auth" action="login.php?logon=logon">
```

and then in `login.php` `$logon` is used right away without any use of `$_POST`.

I'm currently upgrading everything and right now I've got it running php7.0. This method of passing variables no longer works. Because it is so hard to phrase what this is doing I haven't been able to find an example of this online. So I don't know why it worked before and I can't figure out why is doesn't work now. Everyone seems to be using *SESSION* variables or *GLOBAL* variables but because of the many ways this format is used in the code it is impossible to replace it in every case.

Any information about this would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is literally the first lines of login.php. $logon is not in "global_vars.php"

```
<?php
define( 'direct_access', 1 );
include("includes/users.php");
include("includes/global_vars.php");
include("includes/global_functions.php");

if ($logon == "logon"){
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals  maybe...

Comment: Please show some of your php code

Comment: oh boy, legacy code, run while you still can!

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? I could give more examples of this being used.

Comment: Post a code block from where the post request is handled in login.php - especially the part where 'logon' is processed

Comment: in before version also if you have used like "login.php?logon=logon" in login.php you should have accessed though $_GET['logon'].. Am not getting how it worked  $logon ... can you share code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's **extract()** function to import variables into the current symbol table from an array.

```
extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
```

**Documentation:**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I still don't know why the old way was working but adding these to lines to login.php did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite like this to debug and display the values of all variables:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) { // this line was previously if ($logon === "logon"){
    // only reaches here on a post request, i.e. form is submitted

    die(print_r($_REQUEST)); // will show all $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE values that currently are set ---> see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php


}
```

After you confirm the key "logon" is actually present, see if it is present in the $_GET or $_POST array by changing $_REQUEST above (in the die() statement) to $_GET or $_POST.

These may give you clues as to what is happening.

Comment: This is also very useful for future debugging. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm looking at this too simplisticly, but can you not pass the method by POST instead..

```
<form method="post" name="auth" action="login.php">
<input type="hidden" name="logon" value="logon">
```

then in login.php

```
$logon = $_POST['logon'];
```

Alternatively, the use in login.php of..

```
$logon = $_GET['logon'];
```

should still work

Comment: That is the work around I have used in a couple cases but it cannot be used in all of the cases and it does not address the underlying problem.

Comment: $_GET['var'] should retrieve any vars from the URL, so it would be interesting to know why this is an issue for you (an example, perhaps?).